# Receive bson stream in azure function

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions, bson

I have azure function, which accepts huge bson object. It binds to http request and then try to deserialize it using stream with the following code:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await request.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
    using (var reader = new BsonDataReader(stream))
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var readings =
            serializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<ProviderReading>>(reader);
    }
}
```

`readings` object is always null.

I tested it using the standard `ReadAsAsync` method:

```
var test = await request.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ProviderReading>>(
new[]{new BsonMediaTypeFormatter()});
```

in that case it deserialize the collection of readings correctly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CopyTo` (or its `async` variant) advances both the source's and target's position. That means that by the time you construct the `BsonDataReader` the input stream is already at its end.

You should reset the stream's position:

```
stream.Position = 0;
```